# RxJava compatibility with Rsocket

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rsocket, rx-java3

Im going through RSocket implementation for Java using this https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java, but could only find Reactor support(Flux,Mono)
I cannot see any RxJava(Observables) support with RSocket.
Is this understanding correct ?

I tried to go through the code package https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java to see any usage of RxJava variables (Observables).

Is there any standard implementation for Rx with Rsocket with java ?

Comment: I don't know RSocket in detail but it appears to be Reactive Streams compliant. Thus you could simply use `Flowable.fromPublisher`, `Observable.fromPublisher` etc. to switch to RxJava.